# How to add files property to webelement in selenium in python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, request

I have the selenium web element:

 `input_elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("inline_upload")`

 I would like to add to it the file. And then use it in executing js script

`driver.execute_script("func(input_elem);")`

Where func uses this file:

```
func: function(e) {
    a = e.files[0]
    b = attr(e, "some_attr)
}
```

So I have to add files property to my selenium webelement and then init this property with file (binary?), or init new [Input FileUpload Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_fileupload.asp) with selenium.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This example inject an event listener to allow interaction with the uploaded files:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://fiddle.jshell.net/lovlka/N4Jxk/show/")
driver.switch_to_frame(0)

# find the input
input_elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#uploadFile")

# add an event listener on the input element
driver.execute_script("""\
  arguments[0].addEventListener("change", function onchange() {
    this.removeEventListener("change", onchange);
    var files = this.files;

    alert('a file was uploaded');
  });
  """, input_elem)

# upload the file
input_elem.send_keys(r"C:\text.txt")
```

Comment: `print(driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].files", input_elem))` is `[]`

Comment: Is your file correctly uploaded in the input once the send_keys is finished?

Comment: How can I check it? Does another method exist? @florentbr

Comment: You can check it visually on the browser. I've updated the answer with another version that waits for the file to be present. I would be helpful to have a reproducible test case.

Comment: Your code throughs `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Timed out waiting for async script result after 10000ms`.

Visually nothing happens. There is single input without form. It looks like this: `<input type="file" onchange="return ownerPhotoUpload.start(this, event);">`. @florentbr

Comment: It seems that it's only possible to access the files through the event. I've updated the response with a working example on fiddle.

Comment: WHAT IS SHAME! UNBELIEVABLE. I have used wrong type of path. I used

Comment: WHAT IS SHAME! UNBELIEVABLE. I have used wrong type of path. I used relative path instead absolute in send keys! I spent 30 hours for solving it. I thought that developers using great js protection from uploading files. Sorry man)) And thanks a lot! I tried absolute path because you wrote so.